# Unable to mock Mono object

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have been writing unit tests for Spring reactive app. I am trying to stub method response which returns Mono. I tried with samples on the net. But it is giving Null pointer exception. If we can't stub Mono types with Mockito , Please suggest me alternative way.

Complete code is available in below repository
https://github.com/NarayanaBojja/example-service

```
public Mono<Person> getName() { 
    Mono<Person> nameMono = name();
        return nameMono.flatMap(per -> Mono.just(per)).onErrorResume(error -> {
            return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Name not found"));
        });
    }

    public Mono<Person> name() {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("Narayana");
        return Mono.just(person);
    }
```

Unit test case for the above code is

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DemoApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    private ExampleService exampleService;

    @Test
    public void getNameTest() {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("Narayana");
        Mono<Person> nameMono = Mono.just(person);
        given(this.exampleService.name()).willReturn(nameMono);
        StepVerifier.create(exampleService.getName()).expectNext(person).verifyComplete();

    }

}
```

I am getting below Exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:801)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:772)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.verifyComplete(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:644)
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests.getNameTest(DemoApplicationTests.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
```

Comment: I think, here you wanted to test the `ExampleService.getName()` but I see, `ExampleService` is been mocked.

Comment: At least it is handled like it is a mock, but I don't actually see a defintion of it beeing a mock. I also don't see any actual initialisation of `Mockito`.

Comment: There seems to be a couple of problems with your test.
1. You're autowiring a bean of `ExampleService` and then using it as mocked bean.
2. If you're autowiring a bean in your test where are you creating that bean for your test?